# Common customers that got service by specific provider

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 9.1 I have a column of user phone numbers as users and another column of provider's phone numbers as workers who have done some work for our users. How can I find common users that got work of specific providers? For example, I want to know the common users that got serviced by worker a, b, c. I really need this.

Comment: Can you show us your database schema? Use this site if you can: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: How can we help you if you are not helping yourself? Read this [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)